# What cmake project command does?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm wondering how CMake finds the compiler you want to use.
I found that after I called `project`, the variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` is automatically set to GNU. It's sure that when executing cmake command, I gave -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE flag to tell which toolchain file I wanted to use. And in the toolchain file, I specifies `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` as arm-none-eabi-gcc, g++.
However, just setting these variables doesn't mean telling CMake what compiler I'm using right?

According to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html,
it seems that `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is a so-called cmake-variables, which means CMake can parse the contents and do something based on them.
Does CMake read and understand CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER itself, and based on that, CMake automatically sets CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID to GNU or something at the time when `project` is called?

Answer (score 0):

When CMake first encounters a `project()` command, the compiler, linker and several properties based on those are "set in stone". Any adjustments before the first `project()` command can change the compiler cmake chooses, whether you set this via `-D` command line option, toolchain file or via `set()` commands in the `CMakeLists.txt` file. (I strongly recommend not using the last option though, since it limits reuseability.)

If no information was provided, cmake chooses the compiler itself; the exact logic depends on the platform though.

`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` is one of the variables that are set based on the compiler chosen. Basically cmake performs some checks to determine the type of compiler used, the target platform, ect.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I'm still not sure how CMake finds which compiler to choose. Maybe if I set for example `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to `arm-none-eabi-gcc` in the toolchain file, the project command reads the information, and tries to find `arm-none-eabi-gcc` from $PATH. Then CMake tells like oh `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is GNU gcc, so it sets `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` to `GNU`.